# Formulating a Specific HTTP Post Message

Tags: java, android, http, oauth-2.0

I have been combing through example code and tutorials online in an attempt to understand what I am doing wrong here, but I am at a loss. I am developing a Proof of Concept android application to integrate with a Bluetooth Router through a REST API. It requires me to Auth with the back end using a specific HTTP Post message, and all my attempts to replicate this message have failed.

The post message to auth is as follows:

```
POST api/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
 Host: demo.url.com
 Headers: {Authorization: Basic dGVzdGVyOjEfhdjkejlhMmU4MjNjNDc=
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded}

 Body:
{grant_type=client_credentials}
```

And the code I am using to replicate this is:

```
URL url = new URL("http://demo.url.com/api");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("Authorization", "Basic dGVzdGVyOjEfhdjkejlhMmU4MjNjNDc=");
values.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
values.put("Body", "{grant_type=client_credentials}");
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(URLEncoder.encode("data", "UTF-8"));
sb.append("=");
writer.write(sb.toString());
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
conn.connect();
```

Any help, or directions to tutorials or example code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on your http call?

Comment: No, I'm getting a 200 OK reply, but no auth token, I'm getting back HTML for a webpage. I've tested on the manufacturers own tool using the same settings and auth works with my credentials, so I feel the output from android might be in a different format and is being rejected.

Comment: Several tools like request bin https://requestb.in/ exist which are easy to use and you can see exactly what your code is sending. Might help you?

Comment: So when you manually perform the request as shown above it works?

Comment: After putting all the stuff into `values`, you aren't using that variable anymore.

Comment: @Slanik see my answer below. You have to seperate your headers from your body and then put them in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your code should look like for setting up connection. Your content type and authorization are part of headers and will go separately than your body

```
URL url = new URL("http://demo.url.com/api");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic dGVzdGVyOjEfhdjkejlhMmU4MjNjNDc=");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write("{grant_type=client_credentials}");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
conn.connect();
```

Your Body parameters are different and are called as Request parameters and go as a part of the Writer Block. For now I have done it in the same hardcoded manner as you are doing but you have to customize them at a later stage to work for every device and parameters.